# Running C programs using pipes, how to input strings in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

This question is from the book [Programming Pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) 2nd Ed., Column 2, p.20. It's a simple C program that uses a sign.c and squash.c files to sort and squash anagrams (display each group of anagrams on separate lines).

To test the program, I have to run the following line in the terminal:

```
sign <dictionary | sort | squash > gramlist
```

instead of using a file/dictionary, I wanted to enter a small list of words/anagrams and see if the program sorts and squashes the anagrams appropriately.

For example, entering the following words as the input

```
mile lime rot tor break
```

should give me the following output:

```
break
lime mile
rot tor
```

My question : what's the syntax to enter those words as the input? Neither of these works:

```
sign <"mile, lime, rot, tor, break" | sort | squash > output.txt
sign <"mile lime rot tor break" | sort | squash > output.txt
sign <'mile lime rot tor break' | sort | squash > output.txt
sign <'mile, lime, rot, tor, break' | sort | squash > output.txt
sign <mile, lime, rot, tor, break | sort | squash > output.txt
sign <mile lime rot tor break | sort | squash > output.txt
```

The complete code for sign.c and squash.c is [here](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/s02.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

So you know, anything you write with `<` is going to redirect a *file* into your program. Since you want to input a string directly, you need something else. Try:

```
sign <<< "mile lime rot tor break" | sort | squash > output.txt
```

or:

```
echo "mile lime rot tor break" | sign | sort | squash > output.txt
```